# Populating Django Form With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, django

I'm attempting to pass the lat, long using HTML5 geolocation to automatically populate two form fields in a Django form using JavaScript. I've found a new solutions, but the form is a Meta class form where the html is automatically generated, and it doesn't seem to be able to have a manner to add an "id" tag to it for this type of access.

Is there a proper way to access and populate fields in a Meta class form in this manner using JavaScript? Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get the location via HTML5 geolocation, you can use javascript to populate the fields. Look at the generated HTML code of the form & grab the ids of the fields. Here's a sample jQuery code:

```
$("#id_latitude").val(latitude);
$("#id_longitude").val(longitude);
```

Comment: Terrific answer. Got those values. Doesn't appear to be working for some reason. Should the jQuery block be in the form itself or the main js file?

Comment: Put it in the js file. It should be inside the event handler when location is determined.

Comment: Ouch. I'm not assigning global variables to the latitude and longitude correctly. Your answer, though, was excellent. Thanks.

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks. Such an elegant and simple answer. I actually learned something!